# How skip view log on some tables into materialized view for doing fast refresh

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, materialized-views

There is a query where some tables are joined with each other. Due to performance and response time, a materialized view with `fast refresh on commit` is created on it like this:

```
create materialized view mat_calc
refresh fast on commit
as
select po.title as post_title
       po.rowid as post_rowid
       c.title as comment_title,
       c.rowid as comment_rowid,
       p.title as person_title,
       p.rowid as person_rowidو
       cp.rowid as cp_rowid
  from post po, comment c, person p,post_comment_person cp
 where po.id = cp.post_id
   and c.id = cp.comment_id
   and p.id = cp.person_id
```

As you know prerequisite for creating it is `materialized view log` on each of tables that are into this materialized view like this:

```
create materialized view log on post;
create materialized view log on comment;
create materialized view log on person;
create materialized view log on post_comment_person;
```

As you again know, `the materialized view log` is to detect change of these tables and apply change to materialized view.
My problem is that the change of `post_comment_person` table **only** affects my materialized view, due to this fact it is not necessary to create `view log`  on the other three tables; another hand I want that only `post_comment_person` can to refresh not other, but it is impossible and the following error is raised:

> ORA-23413: table "person" does not have a materialized view log.

How can it be done because the change of `person` and `post` and `comment` tables do not matter.

**UPDATE**

Another hand again I want to submit change to the my MV including the change of person and comment and post when a record is inserted to and deleted of post_comment_ person

Comment: apparently a change of the person data will affect the materialized view, because columns of the person table are used in the materialized view.

Comment: Ok yes it is, I want to use the column but it does not do the materialized view refresh. Is it possible?

Comment: So do you want to say that the columns post.title, post.rowid, comment.title, comment.rowid, person.title, person.rowidو will never change? And that there will never be a row deleted from or inserted in the tables post, person and comment? nd that you will never reorganize this tables (this will change the rowid)?

Comment: You assume yes it is. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so. But why do you want to do this?

Comment: I mean the deleted record from and the inserted record to three tables do not matter and I do not want to refresh my MV when record is inserted and deleted of three tables

Comment: Another hand I want to refresh totally my MV including the change of post and comment and person when a record is inserted to and deleted of post_comment_person table

Comment: Another hand again I want to submit change to the my MV including the change of person and comment and post when a record is inserted to and deleted of post_comment_ person

Comment: There are plenty of reasons why a ROWID column might change, you know.

Comment: But why are you trying to do this? Why not just create the mview log and be done with it? If these other tables don't change, then they will be empty and they won't be using any storage or anything.

Comment: All friend I have sent the answer, please look at and comment your ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem of refreshing by changing the **on commit** with  **on demand** for the fast refreshing:

```
create materialized view mat_calc
refresh fast on commit
```

is replaced with:

```
create materialized view mat_calc
refresh fast on demand
```

So after inserting in post_comment_person, I manually refresh my Materialized View in its own trigger like this:

```
DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH( 'mat_calc','f');
```